# How to reload correctly a route in Ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working with the latest release of Ember JS (RC1), and I have an architectural problem :

I have a very simple use case : a list of users, and a form to add users.
My Router:

```
App.Router.map(function () {   
   this.resource('users', function () {
      this.route('new');
   });
});
```

My Routes:

```
App.UsersRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model:function () {
        return App.User.findAll();
    }
});
```

My Controller:

```
App.UsersNewController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    saveUser:function () {
        //'content' contains the user
        App.User.save(this.content);    

        // here i want to reload the list of users, but it doesn't work
        // The application goes correctly to the url /users
        // But doesn't call the 'model' function
        this.transitionToRoute('users');
    }
});
```

As I say in the above comment, when I create a new User, I'd like to redirect to the list of users (that part works) AND reload the user list by calling the 'model' method of the route (that part doesn't).

I could write a method in UsersController to reload the list, but then I would have duplication between UsersRoute and UsersController.

Can someone help me on this problem ?

Thanks

P.S. : here a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vsxXj/

Answer (score 0):

Ember Documentation on the model hook:

> "A hook you can implement to convert the URL into the model for this
>   route."

So i do not think that this hook is right for this case. I think you should use the setupController hook for this case. Try this:

```
App.UsersRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController(controller){
        controller.set("content", App.User.findAll());
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried this solution, but the problem stay the same : the transitionToRoute change correctly the URL and the view, but setupController isn't called, and the model isn't updated

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it?

Comment: Your problems had nothing to do with code you posted. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/mavilein/vsxXj/1/

Comment: You actually did not create a user inside your saveUser function of your Controller.

Comment: Creating user isn't the important part; I want to find the best practice to reload datas from the server while doing a transition to a another view. In my example, 'findAll' isn't logged after 'save'. I can't use your solution, because my server add many informations to the user (id, creation date, etc.) and I'd prefer to reload all the datas.

Comment: Then why don't you do your call to the server inside App.User.findAll()?

Comment: It's what I do on my computer, but the findAll method isn't called after the transitionTo (the console.log show this fact)

Comment: So your question is, why the model hook does not work. Quoting from the ember doc: "A hook you can implement to convert the URL into the model for this route."

Comment: So this hook is not called everytime you transition into this route.

Comment: Ok, I'm only applying http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/, chapter 'resources' and 'dynamic segment'. But I think I've found a solution : extracting the 'new' route from the 'users' resources give the behavior I want : http://jsfiddle.net/vsxXj/4/

Comment: I had the exact same problem and solved it like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818027/what-is-the-right-approach-to-reload-the-model-for-a-non-dynamic-route-with-embe/16820643#16820643