# What is the right approach to reload the model for a non-dynamic route with ember.js?

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js

I'm having a simple array of models which I display in a list (path: /things). The models get loaded from a REST-API.

In a nested route I have the functionality to add a new model.  (path: /things/add). The new model is persisted over a REST-API.

After adding the new model, I do a `transitionTo('things')` to get back to the list.

Following the ember documentation, by using "transitionTo" neither the `model` hook nor the `setupController`-Hook are called for non dynamic routes.

**What is the right approach to refresh the model on a non-dynamic route, when using `transitionTo`? Or: what is the best way to reload a model on a non-dynamic route without using `transitionTo`?**

#### app.js

```
// App Init
App = Ember.Application.create();

// Routes
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('things', function() {
        this.route('add');
    })
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect : function() {
        this.transitionTo('things');
    }
});

App.ThingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(param) {
        return App.Thing.findAll();
    },
});

App.ThingsAddRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController : function(controller) {
        controller.set('content', App.Thing.create());
    }
});

// Models
App.Thing = Ember.Object.extend({
    name : null,
    description : null
});

App.Thing.reopenClass({
    findAll : function() {
        var result;
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://path/app_dev.php/api/things',
            dataType : 'json',
            async : false,
            success : function(data) {
                result = data.things;
            }
        });
        return result;
    },
    save : function(content) {
        console.log(content);
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'http://path/app_dev.php/api/things',
            data : {
                name : content.name,
                description : content.description
            },
            async : false
        });
    }
});

// Controller
App.ThingsAddController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    add : function() {
        App.Thing.save(this.content);
        this.transitionToRoute('things');
    },
    cancelAdding : function() {
        this.transitionToRoute('things');
    }
});
```

#### index.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <h1>List of things</h1>
        </div>
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="things/add">
<div class="span12">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <div id="legend">
                <legend class="">Add new thing</legend>
            </div>

            <!-- Name -->
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    {{view Ember.TextField id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" valueBinding="name"}}
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Description -->
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="description">Description</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    {{view Ember.TextArea id="description" placeholder="Enter description" valueBinding="description"}}
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Submit -->
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" {{action add}}>Save</button>
                    <button class="btn" {{action cancelAdding}}>Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
        </form>
</div>
</script>    

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="things">
<div class="span12">
    <div class="btn-toolbar">
        <div class="btn-group">
            {{#linkTo things.add}}<i class="icon-plus"></i> add new thing{{/linkTo}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{outlet}}  
<div class="span12">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#each item in model}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.description}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you were using ember-data, a side effect of saving the record would be that the results of findAll() get updated. You can accomplish the same by either manually updating the array or triggering a refresh when a new record is added. In either case, suggest doing that from ThingsAddController's add fx. For example:

```
App.ThingsAddController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: [things],
  add : function() {
    newThing = App.Thing.save(this.content);
    this.get('controllers.things').pushObject(newThing);
    this.transitionToRoute('things');
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That actually did it.